# Searching for node attributes in replicated chef server

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have 3 chef servers (version 12) in my infrastructure configured to use replication with chef-sync. One is configured as master and the other two are configured as a slaves.

So far everything works good. But my problem appears when searching for node attributes inside recipes. Each server is only registered in one chef server, so if I want, for example, to get all the IPs of all the nodes using search inside a recipe, I only get a list of the IPs of the nodes registered in the chef server where the current machine is configured.

I think this behaviour is expected, but I was wondering if someone have had the same problem and found a workaround. I will appreciate any hint. Thanks.

Comment: Found solution for this?